# Не работает context.scale(-1, 1);

Tags: javascript

Не работает context.scale(-1, 1) для отражения картинки на канвасе

```
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(-1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(head, 100, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не работает? В приведенном коде вообще нет вызова scale

Comment: поменял код, не работает потому что без скейл рисуется изображение, а с ним не рисуется

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле все работает. Просто при вызове `restore` scale сбрасывается и отрисованное изображение уходит из видимой области.

Чтобы этого избежать можно просто просто исрользовать отрицательные координаты для вывода по оси x.

В этом случае при сбросе `scale` они становятся положительными и вывод становится нормальным:

Пример:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');

function l(img) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(-1, 1);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -200, 0, 100, 100);
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  ctx.restore();

}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas><br/>
<img style="display:none" src="http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png" width="256" height="256" id="t" onload="l(this)">
```